# Is there a way i can do the same for everything in a list except the last element of it?

Tags: c#

This is what i've tried:

```
foreach (var tail in Tails.Skip(Tails.Last))
        {
            //Do stuff here that i dont want to be done on the last element of the list.
        }
```

Ive also tried doing Tails.Count but that made it skip every element in the List... (Tails is the Lists Name)

Comment: If this is, for example, adding separator characters, it's usually best to reframe the task to do something different for the *first* element - that's trivially tracked with a boolean flag to know if you've executed your loop body at least once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you NuGet `System.Interactive` you'll get a bunch of extra `IEnumerable<T>` extensions courtesy of Microsoft. Then you can do this:

```
foreach (var tail in Tails.SkipLast(1))
{
    //Do stuff here that i dont want to be done on the last element of the list.
}
```

Comment: Im rather new to Coding (a few months) so please excuse weird questions but i was thinking about why this works for the past minutes and i cant quite seem to figure it out. What does the (1) do and why is it there? Im really sorry in case this question is dumb...

Comment: @DominikReinold - It because you want to skip the last one item in the list. If you wanted to skip 3 then it would be `.SkipLast(3)`.

Answer (score 5):

use take.  This takes the first n elements from the list and n in your case is Tails.Count -1

```
foreach(var tail in Tails.Take(Tails.Count - 1))
{
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, it worked perfectly! Is that because it needs the index and Tails.Count gives the number of elements in the list? So -1 would make it the actual last index position?

Comment: Tails.Count returns the number of entries in the list - you want to ignore the last element so say your list contains 10 entries you just want to iterate over the first 9 entries.  Take does exactly this, it iterates for the number that you pass in so Tails.Count - 1  would in this case = 9